# error in loading module in angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have search a lot for finding problem in my code but didn't get solution. I'm trying routing in html file there are two links 1 for view1 and second for view2 code for both views are in different files in folder named parts and in js file i have created a module named mymodule my problem is when i remove "mymodule" from an-app in html file then {{ studname }} works fine but after adding "mymodule" i'm getting error

html file code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mymodule">
  <head>
    <title>Try Deep linking</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="" ng-model="studname" />
    <p>{{ studname }}</p>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
    <a href="#/view1">View 1</a>
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS code :

```
var myapp = angular.module("mymodule",[]);

myapp.controller( "mycontroller", function ($scope) {
   $scope.student = [
      {name : "Abhay Sehgal", city: "Delhi" },
      {name : "Pankaj Singh", city: "Bihar" },
      {name : "ujjwal", city : "UP"}
   ];
});

myapp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/view1',{
        controller : "mycontroller",
        templateUrl : "parts/view1.html" 
    })
    .when('/view2',{
        controller : "mycontroller",
        templateUrl : "parts/view2.html" 
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo :'/'});
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the dependency **`ngRoute`** to your module,

```
var myapp = angular.module("mymodule",['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: solved..thanks a lot..seriously i'm doing a silly mistake...thanks once again